# Right column misaligned in table

Tags: tables

I have a simple table with four columns. Strangely, the last column, the right-most one, compiles as if it was "away" from the others. Why would this be? It is very annoying. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]

\caption{Title goes here}
\label{tab:regression2}
\centering
\resizebox{0.9\textwidth}{!}{
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
\hline\hline
        &              Placement    &         Placement         &        Placement            &        Placement            \\
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{      \small{Model E}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small{Model F}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small{Model G}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small{Model H }}\\
\hline

Treatment 1     &   -10.61\sym{**} &                  &   -3.811         &         0         \\
                &  (0.048)         &                  &  (0.677)         &        ($\cdot$)          \\
[1em]

Sample Score    &                  &    1.332\sym{***}&    3.813\sym{*}  &        1.732\sym{***}          \\
                &                  &  (0.237)         &  (0.061)         &        (0.007)            \\ 
                [1em]
Treat.1 \textit{X} Sample Score&    7.005\sym{***}&    2.064\sym{**} &    3.245         &         2.064\sym{**}          \\
                &  (0.002)         &  (0.046)         &  (0.283)         &        (0.046)          \\
[1em]
Male            &    5.031\sym{**} &    4.526\sym{*}  &    4.524\sym{*}  &          4.526\sym{*}         \\
                &  (0.032)         &  (0.054)         &  (0.054)         &         (0.154)         \\


Constant        &    44.57\sym{***}&    16.17\sym{***}&    37.40\sym{***}&   46.17\sym{***}        \\
                &  (0.000)         &  (0.000)         &  (0.000)         &      (0.000)        \\
\hline

\hline
N               &      282         &      282         &      282         &      282         \\
$R^2$              &   0.0648         &   0.0761         &   0.0767         &   0.0761         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize NOTES: The dependent variable is placement (the reported belief that own performance in the quiz is }\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize above the median). Models E-G are OLS regressions. Model H is a semi-structural estimation }\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize imposing the model's  restriction that $Treatment 1 >0$.  }\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{P}-values in parentheses. \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\).}\\
\end{tabular}
}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Thank you. I am using TexStudio to make this. I have tried to use the code from the answer here
[in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222494/using-multicolumncolspwidth-sets-last-column-inappropriate), but, although it improves, it is not perfect and TexStudio returns an error: illegal character, in the line of begin{tabular}).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you! Hope to ask good questions (and someday know enough to answer some!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would redesign your table as follows:

[image]

- not use `\resizebox`
- for columns with numbers use `S` columns defined in the `siunitx` package; it enables aligning numbers at decimal points
- for "Note" below table use `p{\linewidth}` column type (your with `l` is source of your problem)
- instead `\hline`s is nicer to use rules from the package `booktabs`

**Edit**:
as sugested @leandriis in his comment below:

- for the first row in table use `\multicolumn{4}{c}{...}`, since it is better to have common word "Placement" for all columns with numbers.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
\caption{Title goes here}
\label{tab:regression2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{S[input-symbols = {( )},
                        table-space-text-post ={$^{***}$},
                        table-align-text-post=false,
                        table-format=2.3]}}
    \toprule
    &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Placement}                                                 \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
\\
    &\small Model E &\small Model F         &\small Model G     &\small Model H     \\
    \midrule
Treatment 1     
    & -10.61\sym{**}    &                   & -3.811            &  0                \\
    &  (0.048)          &                   & (0.677)           & ($\cdot$)         \\
    \addlinespace
Sample Score    
    &                   &  1.332\sym{***}   &  3.813\sym{*}     &  1.732\sym{***}   \\
    &                   & (0.237)           & (0.061)           &  (0.007)          \\
    \addlinespace
Treat.1 \textit{X} Sample Score
    &   7.005\sym{***}  &  2.064\sym{**}    &  3.245            &  2.064\sym{**}    \\
    &  (0.002)          &  (0.046)          &  (0.283)          & (0.046)           \\
    \addlinespace
Male            
    &   5.031\sym{**}   &   4.526\sym{*}    &   4.524\sym{*}    &  4.526\sym{*}     \\
    &  (0.032)          &  (0.054)          &  (0.054)          & (0.154)           \\
    \addlinespace
Constant        
    &  44.57\sym{***}   & 16.17\sym{***}    &  37.40\sym{***}   & 46.17\sym{***}    \\
    &  (0.000)          & (0.000)           &  (0.000)          & (0.000)           \\
    \midrule
N   & {282}             & {282}             & {282}             & {282}             \\
$R^2$              
    &   0.0648          &   0.0761          &   0.0767          &  0.0761           \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{5}{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}{\footnotesize 
NOTES: The dependent variable is placement (the reported belief that own performance in the quiz is above the median). Models E-G are OLS regressions. Model H is a semi-structural estimation 
imposing the model's  restriction that $Treatment 1 >0$. 

$P$-values in parentheses. \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\).} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use a `\multicolumn{4}{c}` for "Placement Model"  and a `\cmidrule` in the table header.

Comment: @leandriis, you are right. With this improvement table will become even nicer. done! thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you both. This definitely works. I have a colleague who uses Scientific Workplace, however, so I had to skip using the siunitx package (at least this time) because it does not work in SWP. Sadly, the notes are missing when using SWP, too. Any ideas on that? Using the code I posted, it works well (but with the misaligned column, of course).

Comment: @JuanPedro, your problem with SWP is one more reason why is better use pure LaTeX :-). Concerning SWP I can't help you, I don't use it. About it I suggest you to ask a new question here or on SWP support, if it exist. Regarding your question, I belive, that answer solve what you asked for, so you can accept it :-)

Comment: Yes, I know. My colleague is the stubborn one, not me, so I am stuck. Thank you very much. I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Building upon [Zarko's great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501982/134144), here is a slight variant that uses the `threeparttable` package in order to ensure that the table notes are automatically as wide as the table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Title goes here}
\label{tab:regression2}
\sisetup{input-symbols = {( )},
         table-space-text-post ={$^{***}$},
         table-align-text-post=false}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[table-format=-2.3]S[table-format=2.3]}}
    \toprule
    &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Placement Model}                                                 \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
    &  {E} &  {F}         &  {G}     &  {H}     \\
    \midrule
Treatment 1     
    & -10.61\sym{**}    &                   & -3.811            &  0                \\
    &  (0.048)          &                   & (0.677)           & ($\cdot$)         \\
    \addlinespace
Sample Score    
    &                   &  1.332\sym{***}   &  3.813\sym{*}     &  1.732\sym{***}   \\
    &                   & (0.237)           & (0.061)           &  (0.007)          \\
    \addlinespace
Treat.1 \textit{X} Sample Score
    &   7.005\sym{***}  &  2.064\sym{**}    &  3.245            &  2.064\sym{**}    \\
    &  (0.002)          &  (0.046)          &  (0.283)          & (0.046)           \\
    \addlinespace
Male            
    &   5.031\sym{**}   &   4.526\sym{*}    &   4.524\sym{*}    &  4.526\sym{*}     \\
    &  (0.032)          &  (0.054)          &  (0.054)          & (0.154)           \\
    \addlinespace
Constant        
    &  44.57\sym{***}   & 16.17\sym{***}    &  37.40\sym{***}   & 46.17\sym{***}    \\
    &  (0.000)          & (0.000)           &  (0.000)          & (0.000)           \\
    \midrule
N   & {282}             & {282}             & {282}             & {282}             \\
$R^2$              
    &   0.0648          &   0.0761          &   0.0767          &  0.0761           \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]

\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}\setlength\labelsep{0pt}\footnotesize
\item{NOTES:} The dependent variable is placement (the reported belief that own performance in the quiz is above the median). Models E-G are OLS regressions. Model H is a semi-structural estimation 
imposing the model's  restriction that $Treatment 1 >0$. 

$P$-values in parentheses. \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\).
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

With the `threeparttablex` package you could also make use of the `\note` command. This might be especially useful if you later on decide that you would like the word "note" to be printed in a different style (italic, bold, not all uppercase,...).

To use this, replace `\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}` from the above example with `\usepackage[flushleft, para, referable]{threeparttablex}
\renewcommand\TPTLnotesnamefontcommand{\MakeUppercase}` and `\item{NOTES:}` with `\note`.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: If you would use `threeparttablex` package with option `referable`, than you can use in `tablenotes` command `\note` like this: `\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, para] \footnotesize \note <note text> \end{tablenotes}` :-)

Comment: @Zarko: Thank you for your great idea and for showing me yet another package that I did not know before. :)