# Misplaced omit error in table

Tags: tables

I have been looking for an answer (in this site and others) for about three hours, commented out the vast majority of my code, and I still have no answer to my issue. I have a table which returns multiple misplaced \omit and misplaced \span errors. Why is this happening? It must be something very silly, I guess. This is my code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode{}^{#1}\else\({}^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
%TCIMACRO{%
%\TeXButton{B}{\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
%\begin{table}[h]\centering}}%
%BeginExpansion
\begin{table}[h]\centering%
%EndExpansion
\caption{Heterogeneous effect - The role of confidence} \label%
{tab:regression2}%
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline\hline
& Placement & Placement & Placement & Placement \\ 
& {\small {Model E}} & {\small {Model F}} & {\small {Model G}} & {\small {%
Model H }} \\ \hline
Treatment 1 & -10.61\sym{**} &  & -2.811 & 0 \\ 
& (0.048) &  & (0.677) & ($\cdot $) \\[1em] 
Sample Score &  & 4.332\sym{***} & 3.813\sym{*} & 4.332\sym{***} \\ 
&  & (0.007) & (0.061) & (0.007) \\[1em] 
Treat.1 $X$ Sample Score & 7.005\sym{***} & 2.064\sym{**} & 3.245 & 
2.064\sym{**} \\ 
& (0.002) & (0.046) & (0.283) & (0.046) \\[1em] 
Male & 5.031\sym{**} & 4.526\sym{*} & 4.524\sym{*} & 4.526\sym{*} \\ 
& (0.032) & (0.054) & (0.054) & (0.054) \\ 
Constant & 54.57\sym{***} & 46.17\sym{***} & 47.40\sym{***} & 46.17\sym{***} \\ %
& (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) \\ \hline\hline
N & 282 & 282 & 282 & 282 \\ 
$R^{2}$ & 0.0648 & 0.0761 & 0.0767 & 0.0761 \\ \hline\hline
\end{tabular}%
\smallskip

\multicolumn{4}{p{0.85\linewidth}}{\footnotesize NOTES: The dependent variable is placement (the reported belief that own performance in the quiz is above the median). Models E-G are OLS regressions. Model H is a semi-structural estimation imposing the model's restriction that Treatment $1>0$. \textit{P}-values in parentheses. \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.10\), \sym{***} \(p<0.10\).} \\
%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{E}{\end{table}}}%
%BeginExpansion
\end{table}%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I know the spacing is bad but it should work. Please note that a colleague of mine uses Scientific Workplace, which has serious compatibility issues. That is why I use the multicolumn after the \end{tabular} and I avoid using packages such as booktabs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But `\multicolumn` _can't_ go outside a `tabular` environment. I think you can replace `\multicolumn{4}{p{0.85\linewidth}}` by `\parbox{0.85\linewidth}` or something like that to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Well, I swear I took the advice of putting the multicolumn outside the tabular from a great answer somewhere in another question, a few weeks ago. I cannot find it now... Anyways, your suggestion works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could ues the `threeparttable` package as shown in my answer to one of your previous questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502001/134144

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
 \multicolumn{4}{p{0.85\linewidth}}{\footnotesize NOTES: The dependent variable is placement (the reported belief that own performance in the quiz is above the median). Models E-G are OLS regressions. Model H is a semi-structural estimation imposing the model's restriction that Treatment $1>0$. \textit{P}-values in parentheses. \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.10\), \sym{***} \(p<0.10\).} \\
```

outside the tabular, hence the error. simply use

```
 \footnotesize NOTES: The dependent variable is placement (the reported belief that own performance in the quiz is above the median). Models E-G are OLS regressions. Model H is a semi-structural estimation imposing the model's restriction that Treatment $1>0$. \textit{P}-values in parentheses. \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.10\), \sym{***} \(p<0.10\).
```

Comment: Thank you. This works but is not perfect, since I want the notes to be aligned with the table. I have tested Phelype Oleinik's suggestion in the comment and it seems to do the trick.

Comment: also see the `threeparttable` evironment from the package of the same name that provides a properly aligned notes construct @JuanPedro

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is (of course) to place multicolumn inside the tabular and add a vertical space by a new empty line plus a negative space in `[]` after `\\`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode{}^{#1}\else\({}^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
%TCIMACRO{%
%\TeXButton{B}{\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
%\begin{table}[h]\centering}}%
%BeginExpansion
\begin{table}[h]\centering%
%EndExpansion
\caption{Heterogeneous effect - The role of confidence} \label%
{tab:regression2}%
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\hline\hline
& Placement & Placement & Placement & Placement \\ 
& {\small {Model E}} & {\small {Model F}} & {\small {Model G}} & {\small {%
Model H }} \\ \hline
Treatment 1 & -10.61\sym{**} &  & -2.811 & 0 \\ 
& (0.048) &  & (0.677) & ($\cdot $) \\[1em] 
Sample Score &  & 4.332\sym{***} & 3.813\sym{*} & 4.332\sym{***} \\ 
&  & (0.007) & (0.061) & (0.007) \\[1em] 
Treat.1 $X$ Sample Score & 7.005\sym{***} & 2.064\sym{**} & 3.245 & 
2.064\sym{**} \\ 
& (0.002) & (0.046) & (0.283) & (0.046) \\[1em] 
Male & 5.031\sym{**} & 4.526\sym{*} & 4.524\sym{*} & 4.526\sym{*} \\ 
& (0.032) & (0.054) & (0.054) & (0.054) \\ 
Constant & 54.57\sym{***} & 46.17\sym{***} & 47.40\sym{***} & 46.17\sym{***} \\ %
& (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) \\ \hline\hline
N & 282 & 282 & 282 & 282 \\ 
$R^{2}$ & 0.0648 & 0.0761 & 0.0767 & 0.0761 \\ \hline\hline\\[-0.5em]
\multicolumn{4}{p{0.85\linewidth}}{\footnotesize NOTES: The dependent variable is placement (the reported belief that own performance in the quiz is above the median). Models E-G are OLS regressions. Model H is a semi-structural estimation imposing the model's restriction that Treatment $1>0$. \textit{P}-values in parentheses. \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.10\), \sym{***} \(p<0.10\).} \\
\end{tabular}%
%TCIMACRO{\TeXButton{E}{\end{table}}}%
%BeginExpansion
\end{table}%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use `threepartablex` for table's notes and `siunitx` for writing numbers in table:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode{}^{#1}\else\({}^{#1}\)\fi}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering%
    \begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Heterogeneous effect - The role of confidence} 
\label{tab:regression2}%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
            l *{4}{S[input-symbols = {()},
                     table-space-text-post=***,
                     round-integer-to-decimal,
                     round-mode=places,
                     round-precision=3,
                     table-format=-2.3]}
                            }
    \toprule
    &   {\thead{Placement\\ Model E}} 
        &   {\thead{Placement\\ Model F}}
            &   {\thead{Placement\\ Model G}}
                &      {\thead{Placement\\ Model H}}                                \\ 
    \midrule
Treatment 1     
    & -10.61\tnote{**}  &                   & -2.811            & 0                 \\
    & (0.048)           &                   & (0.677)           & {$(\cdot)$}       \\
    \addlinespace
Sample Score    
    &                   & 4.332\tnote{***}  & 3.813\tnote{*}    & 4.332\tnote{***}  \\
    &                   & (0.007)           & (0.061)           & (0.007)           \\
    \addlinespace
Treat.1 $X$ Sample Score 
    & 7.005\tnote{***}  & 2.064\tnote{**}   & 3.245             & 2.064\tnote{**}   \\
    & (0.002)           & (0.046)           & (0.283)           & (0.046)           \\ 
    \addlinespace
Male            
    & 5.031\tnote{**}   & 4.526\tnote{*}    & 4.524\tnote{*}    & 4.526\tnote{*}    \\
    & (0.032)           & (0.054)           & (0.054)           & (0.054)           \\
    \addlinespace
Constant        
    & 54.57\tnote{***}  & 46.17\tnote{***}  & 47.40\tnote{***}  & 46.17\tnote{***}  \\
    & (0.000)           & (0.000)           & (0.000)           & (0.000)           \\
    \midrule
N   & {282}             & {282}             & {282}             & {282}             \\
$R^{2}$         
    & 0.0648            & 0.0761            & 0.0767            & 0.0761            \\ 
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, para]\footnotesize
\note 
The dependent variable is placement (the reported belief that own performance in the quiz is above the median). Models E-G are OLS regressions. Model H is a semi-structural estimation imposing the model's restriction that Treatment $1>0$. 

\textit{P}-values are in parentheses: 
\item[*] \(p<0.10\), 
\item[**] \(p<0.10\), 
\item[***] \(p<0.10\).
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}%
    \end{table}%
\end{document}
```